# Что означает ключевое слово tov при объявление структуры

Tags: c, стандарт

Для чего служит ключевое слово tov в следующем фрагменте кода?:

```
struct tov {char name[30]; float c; int kol;} t1;
```

Ниже приведена вся функция где происходит работа с данной структурой:

```
    void find(FILE *tf) {
  char c, tov[10];
  long int i;
  tf = fopen("file1.dat", "rb+");  // открытие бинарного файла для чтения и записи
  system("cls");  // Очистка окна консоли от старых данных
  puts(" The name of : ");
  gets(tov);
  fread(&t1, sizeof(t1), 1, tf);
  while (!feof(tf)) {
    if (strcmp(t1.name, tov) == 0) {
      printf("Product: %10s  Price: %6.2f Amount: %d", t1.name, t1.c, t1.kol);
      printf("\n change? y/n ");
      c = getch();
      if (c == 'y') {
        printf("\n amount: ");
        scanf("%d", &t1.kol);
        printf("\n price: ");
        scanf("%f", &t1.c);
        i = sizeof(t1);
        fseek(tf, -i, 1);  // возврат на sizeof(t1) байт назад
        fwrite(&t1, sizeof(t1), 1, tf);  // запись изменённой структуры на прежнее место
      }
    }
    fread(&t1, sizeof(t1), 1, tf);
  }
  fclose(tf);
}
```

Comment: товарищь майор?

Comment: `tov` в первом примере - это имя структуру. А `tov` во втором примере - имя локальной переменной, причем приведенная функция с этой структурой не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не ключевое слово, а имя структуры, как типа данных. После этого вы можете объявлять переменные этого типа как

```
struct tov t1, t2;
```

так же, как делаете это с другими типами, наподобие

```
int i, j;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

это не ключевое слово, это название структуры